# My new ethernet adapter device that I plugged doesnt seem to work

Tags: windows-10, bios, motherboard, network-adapter, hardware-detection

My onboard ethernet that came with my motherboard is limited to 100mbps and so I bought a new one (Gigabit Pci-express X1 Realtek 10/100/1000mb), it shows on my devices on windows (windows 10 pro), but it doesnt seem to work, i tried updating drivers, reconecting, updating windows, etc. The seller told me that I should try to disable my onboard at BIOS but there is no option for such, I tried disabling at windows devices but didnt work either.

[image: The device shows to be plugged, My Devices -> Network Adapters -> Realtek PCIe GBe Family Controller#2]

Edit> I added the images you guys asked, there is a red light that blinks at the new adapter occasionally.

[CMD after ipconfig while ethernet cable conected to adapter #2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZOaq.png)

[Ethernet 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjBdf.png)

[All network devices.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkrXo.png)

Comment: You can run more than one NIC at a time, and that SHOULD  take priority over a fast ethernet adaptor (not that anything modern should come with just fast ethernet). Could you plug in to the 'new' adaptor and give the output of ipconfig?

Comment: Your onboard one being limited to 100mbps is strange given that both network controllers listed are GbE (gigabit ethernet) so that would suggest that both of these is from the same controller. Do they have 2 ethernet ports too? And what is the 3rd device in that list? is that your onboard one?

Comment: How exactly does it not work? Does Windows show it as "not connected" or something else? Do the LEDs on the card (may be integrated with the RJ45 port) light up when connecting the cable? Are you sure the cable is okay? Can you perhaps test it with another device?

Comment: Ethernet devices are controlled from Windows, not from BIOS. Ignore that advice.

Comment: A broken cable could also result in 100mbit connection. Unless your pc is ancient, you likely have a 1Gbps network card onboard already.

Comment: @harrymc not necessarily true.  Some motherboards allow you to disable the network card from their bios in a similar way to disable usb ports and other peripherals. While this should not be causing issues at all in windows, it can be a good test regardless. Just to rule things out.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, LPChip, Daniel B, I added some pictures that you guys asked, by the way thank you all for the support you are giving.

Comment: Switch back to your build-in network port: Does it still work, but at 100 MBit/s? It may have been intentionally limited (in software) to work around a bad connection. Please describe where the Ethernet connection goes. Does it go to a switch directly? Or maybe to a wall socket? If so, where does it go from the wall socket? Please describe the entire connection to the next “active” device (computer, switch, router, modem, …).

Comment: Daniel, when I turn back to my build-in network port it does work, but its limited to 100mbit/s, I got my modem connected to my computer via cat6 ethernet cable